# Sending message to Discord channel

Tags: c#, discord

What I want to achieve:

I want to send message on Discord channel whenever console_app.exe is executed by an external program, so I decided to use pure rest:

I created APP  via `https://discord.com/developers/applications`

I have ClientId and ClientSecret and now I'd want to sign in from code and send message on specific channel

I'm obtaining Token without problems with response like:

```
{
  "access_token": "6qrZcUqja781...HBFG",
  "token_type": "Bearer",
  "expires_in": 604800,
  "scope": "identify connections"
}
```

but when I try to send message (function `WriteMessage`) then I'm `Unauthorized` for some reason

The whole code:

```
private static readonly RestClient client = new RestClient("https://discord.com");

public string Perform()
{
    client.Authenticator = new HttpBasicAuthenticator(_config.ClientId, _config.ClientSecret);
    var token = GetToken();
    client.Authenticator = null;
    return WriteMessage(token);
}
```

---

```
private string GetToken()
{
    var signInRequest = new RestRequest("/api/v6/oauth2/token", Method.POST);
    signInRequest.AddHeader("content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
    signInRequest.AddParameter("grant_type", "client_credentials");
    signInRequest.AddParameter("scope", "identify connections");

    var result = client.Execute<AuthResult>(signInRequest);

    return result.Data.access_token;
}
```

---

```
private string WriteMessage(string token)
{
    var request = new RestRequest("/api/v8/channels/.../messages", Method.POST);

    request.AddHeader("Authorization", $"Bearer {token}");
    //request.AddHeader("Authorization", $"{token}");
    
    var msg = new DiscordMessage
    {
        content = "Test",
        nonce = "78714914815023104",
        tts = false
    };

    request.AddJsonBody(msg);

    IRestResponse response = client.Execute(request);
    var content = response.Content;

    Console.WriteLine(response.StatusCode); // Unauthorized
    Console.WriteLine(response.Content);
    return content;
}
```

What I may be doing wrong?

Comment: Are you perhaps requesting something outside your scopes? If your only scope is "identify connections", that might be an issue I guess.

Comment: @sunero4 I tried scopes like `bot` `identify bot` and still none worked :/

Comment: @Axelly Is it an app or a bot? The Discord API docs differentiate the two. Are you wanting to send a message on behalf of a user? Or are you wanting to send a message as a bot?

Comment: @jandrew I want anything that will allow me to execute my console app and it will send message on channel - what should I try to use? bot or app?

Comment: You can try and use [Fiddler](https://www.telerik.com/fiddler) to look into the request you're sending. Maybe by looking at the request itself you can figure out if something is missing.

Comment: are you able to send a message using other means to hit Discord's API? Tools like [Postman](https://www.postman.com/) can help to you verify that your keys/token are working before you try to execute them in console app.

Comment: from the [docs](https://discord.com/developers/docs/resources/channel#create-message), it appears you must connect to [gateway](https://discord.com/developers/docs/topics/gateway) before posting a message. i presume you have done it somewhere else?

Comment: @timur no, I didn't, that's the whole code. Thanks. I'll try this soon

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's solution using Discord.NET

```
public DiscordWrapper(string token)
{
    _token = token;
}

public async Task SendMessage()
{
    _client = new DiscordSocketClient();

    await _client.LoginAsync(TokenType.Bot, _token);
    await _client.StartAsync();

    // this is important
    // found it here:
    // https://github.com/discord-net/Discord.Net/issues/1100
    _client.Ready += _client_Ready;

     await Task.Delay(-1);
}

private async Task _client_Ready()
{
    var guild = _client.GetGuild(7....3); // guild id

    var channel = guild.GetTextChannel(79034....63); // channel id

    await channel.SendMessageAsync("my_message");

    Environment.Exit(0);
}
```

Answer (score 7):

It might be easier to use this C# API which is quite popular on github: https://github.com/discord-net/Discord.Net

Writing auth from scratch can be painful.

It's worth a few minutes to try the library maybe it just works. You'll want to read the readme as there are 4 add-on nuget packages as well that might interest you.